# QGIS 3.10.5 Installation aborted

Tags: installation, windows-10, 64bit, qgis-3

I'm trying to download QGIS 3.10.5 64-bit to my Windows 10 Laptop, but for some reason, the installation decided to cancel.

It stopped nearly 4/5 of the way when running the `'Extract:qgis_zh-Hans.qm'`. I got a notification that the Installation was aborted and that the setup was not completed successfully.

I have enough space on my hard drive, so I'm not sure what the problem is here. Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Erik Nothing yet.. I'm honestly not sure where to start

Comment: Then try the whole repertoire: Update drivers, make sure, it's a clean, new installation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! All the drivers are up to date so that wasn't the problem. Trying to download the 32-bit version now to see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

When I checked via [4 Ways To Tell If You’re Using 32-Bit Or 64-Bit Windows](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-tell-if-youre-using-32-bit-or-64-bit-windows/) it turns out my computer couldn't handle the 64-bit version.

By downloading the 32-bit version the problem was solved.